# $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ as inverse limit

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

I'm studying a proof that $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is profinite, but I'm stuck in one point.

If $a$ is a matrix, then $a^{(i,j)}$ denotes the entries of $a$.

The idea is show that
$$SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p) \simeq \varprojlim_i SL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}).$$
In order to show the isomorphism, the author uses the natural projection maps $\epsilon_m: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}$ and defines the homomorphism $\alpha: SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p) \to \varprojlim_i SL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z})$ by $g \mapsto (g_m)_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}$ where $g_m^{(i,j)} = \epsilon_m(g^{(i,j)})$. So, he claims that $\alpha$ is continuous because
$$S_m = \prod_{i=1}^m \{1\} \times \prod_{i=m}^{\infty}SL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z})$$
form a base for the neighborhoods of the identity of inverse limit and $\alpha^{-1}(S_m) = SL_n(p^m\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is open in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

> I cannot see why $\alpha^{-1}(S_m) = SL_n(p^m\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

The proof can be found in [this link](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Edanielch/thesis/smyth.pdf).

Comment: It's "matrix", not "matriz".

Comment: Example $1.26$ [here](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/thesis/smyth.pdf) has more details.

Comment: And is perhaps just the proof you are referring to (so, good to link it). What is the image of $\alpha$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes. This is exactly the proof I'm reading. The imagem of $\alpha$ is exactly the inverse limit, since it is an isomorphism, so its a closed subgroup of cartesian product $\prod_i SL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z})$.